# laws of logic - having issues with identifying if some propositions and what law is used

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

```
(~q∨q)∧r⇔(q∨~q)∧r

(q∨~q)∧r⇔r∧(q∨~q)
```

To me looking over all the laws the only one that I think that makes sense to me is the Commutative law. Unless I am just way overthinking it and missing something simple that it uses a different law or laws. Here are some others that I had no problem identifying I believe. This is all refresher before my course starts this summer where we start writing our own proofs:

```
 r∧(q∨~q)⇔r∧t           Negation of Laws
 r∧t⇔r                  Identity Law
 r∧(q∨~q)⇔(r∧q)∨(r∧~q)  Distributive Law
 ~(q→p)⇔q∧~p            Negation of Conditional
```

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Yes, the commutative law says those equivalences at the top of your question hold

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).